# Using Csv Or Xml for solr Import file?

Tags: xml, csv, solr

I wanna use SOLR for and application. i get my data from SQl.
I just need to know the pons and cons about using CSV and XML for importing.

thank you so much.

Comment: If you're retrieving data from a database why not consider avoiding an intermediate file format and use the DataImportHandler (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler)? Another alternative is a programming library like Solrj (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Solr, there is no difference -- it's just an import format, whereby you create data and PUSH it into Solr. As Mark pointed out in his comment, you could also use a DataImportHandler and PULL data from your data source into Solr.

There could be advantages, such as file sizes for very large data sets, but that's just generic comparisons about CSV/XML/JSON/etc. In the end, it's just a way to format your data and let Solr interpret that for insert/update to your search index.

Comment: so you say there is no difference even for multivalued data?

Comment: If I understand your question, no -- there is no difference. Solr supports multivalued fields in CSV data via the split parameter.